# How to ban users for a certain period of time in Nestjs and mongodb?

Tags: nestjs

I want to Implement **Ban** functionality with **Nestjs and Mongodb**. Admin can ban a user for a certain period of time or block for a certain period of time. And after that period of time the ban functionality will be automatically removed and user can login again.

It might be happen like this...

If we want to ban some one we can change his role, for example user(1) to ban(0). And for next 7 days the role will be ban(0). And after the 7th day the role will automatically convert into user(1). And user can see how many days are left until the ban restriction is removed from his account.

**But I'm getting nothing from internet on this topic. Can anybody tell how do we implement this functionality? Or any blog or document which can help...**

Comment: I think you just described how to do it.   You have a background process that once a day wakes up, looks for 7 day old bans, and changes the permissions back to normal.   More broadly, this is not a mongodb question.

Comment: But I can only change the `role`, I don't know how to set day limit according to role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for task scheduling:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling

You can execute a function periodically and either delete users or update their role depending on your business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the answer and the documentation of Nestjs, **@mh377** provided, I tried and made a code according to my question, There is soo much to Improve here but for initial steps I tried to explain how changing a role and reversing it automatically after sometime, can be done in Nests with MongoDb.

**Add a new Property in the `MongoDb Schema`. The `@ApiProperty()` is for `swagger-ui` documentation**. The `isActive` will be used to ban and unban users on the basis of `true` and `false` values. Every new user that is registered is set to `true` by default which means he has access

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @Prop({ required: true, default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
```

**Install The Following Task Scheduling Dependencies**

```
$ npm install --save @nestjs/schedule
$ npm install --save-dev @types/cron
```

**Register it in app.module.ts. You can register it in other modules as well. If You working in some other nested module or else...**

```
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  ],
})
```

**user.service.ts. Register `SchedulerRegistry` in constructor**

```
constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name) private readonly userModel: Model<userDocument>,
    private scheduler: SchedulerRegistry,
  ) {}
```

**user.service.ts. Function to ban a user and remove the restriction after 10 seconds automatically. You can manage the time according to your requirements. If You won't stop the `job` it will start executing after 10 seconds again and again in an infinite loop**

`new CronJob()` **is  the NestJs Task Scheduling Part**

```
import { CronExpression, SchedulerRegistry } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

private banned: userDocument;
private banRemoved: userDocument;
 
  async banUser(id: string): Promise<userDocument> {

    let user: User = await this.userModel.findById({ _id: id });

    user.isActive = false;

    banned = await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, user, {
      new: true,
    });

    console.log('Baned User', banned);

    const job: CronJob = new CronJob(
      CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS,
      async () => {
        let user: User = await this.userModel.findById({ _id: id });

        user.isActive = true;

        banRemoved = await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, user, {
          new: true,
        });

        console.log('Revoked', banRemoved);
      },
    );

    this.scheduler.addCronJob('name', job);
    job.start();

    setTimeout(() => {
      job.stop();
    }, 10100);

    return banRemoved;
  }
```

**user.controller.ts**

```
 @Patch('banUser/:id')
  async banUser(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<userDocument> {
    return await this.userService.banUser(id);
  }
```

**Hit endpoint to check**

```
nestjs-server-port / @Controller('name') / httprequest-decorator('name') / userId

http://localhost:3000/users/banUser/639b47a25Lef4ddd7a48bb60
```